# SameAs Assertion calling setter with VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, nunit

Have I found some odd behavior in nUnit?

The following VB.Net test fails with:

```
Test 'SameAsTest.UseSameAs' failed: 
  Expected string length 19 but was 29. Strings differ at index 19.
  Expected: "Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get"
  But was:  "Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get,Prop1 Set"

  ------------------------------^
    SameAsTest.vb(33,0): at SameAsTest.UseSameAs()

1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.80 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

---

```
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports NUnit.Framework

<TestFixture()>
Public Class SameAsTest

    Private CallHistory As List(Of String)
    Private mPropValue As String = "ThisIsIt"


    Public Property Prop1 As String
        Get
            CallHistory.Add("Prop1 Get")
            Return mPropValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            CallHistory.Add("Prop1 Set")
            mPropValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <SetUp()>
    Public Sub Setup()
        CallHistory = New List(Of String)
    End Sub

    <Test()>
    Public Sub UseSameAs()
        Assert.That(Prop1, [Is].SameAs(Prop1))
        Assert.That(String.Join(",", CallHistory.ToArray()), [Is].EqualTo("Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get"))
    End Sub

    <Test()>
    Public Sub UseAreSame()
        Assert.AreSame(Prop1, Prop1)
        Assert.That(String.Join(",", CallHistory.ToArray()), [Is].EqualTo("Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

when the c# equiv works fine:

```
2 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 0.19 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework ;

    [TestFixture ]
    class Dummy
    {

        private List<String> CallHistory;
        private String mPropValue = "ThisIsIt";

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            CallHistory = new List<string>();
        }

        public String Prop1 
        {
            get
            {
            CallHistory.Add("Prop1 Get");
            return mPropValue;
            }
            set
            {
                CallHistory.Add("Prop1 Set");
                mPropValue = value;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void UseSameAs()
        {
            Assert.That(Prop1, Is.SameAs(Prop1));
            Assert.That(String.Join(",", CallHistory.ToArray()), Is.EqualTo("Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get"));

        }

        [Test]
        public void UseaAreSame()
        {
            Assert.AreSame(Prop1, Prop1);
            Assert.That(String.Join(",", CallHistory.ToArray()), Is.EqualTo("Prop1 Get,Prop1 Get"));

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't actually the call to `SameAs`.  The problem is the property being passed as the first parameter of the `Assert.That` call.

`Assert.That` has many different overloads and it turns out that the overload resolution is done differently in VB to C#.  In C#, the property is being matched against:

```
Asset.That(object actual, IResolveConstraint expression);
```

In VB, it's being matched against:

```
Assert.That<Of T>(ByRef T actual, IResolveConstraint express);
```

Since the VB version is actually passing a non reference property value to a method expecting a reference it appears to be simulating a reference pass by creating a local string, passing it by reference into the method and then setting the value of the property to the returned value of the string.  I'm not sure why it's choosing the function this way, hardcore VB programmers might be able to explain it.

You can get around it either by declaring a local variable and using it for the first parameter:

```
Dim prop1 = Prop1
Assert.That(prop1, [Is].SameAs(Prop1))
```

Or by casting the parameter to force it to use the expected overload of the `That` method.

```
Assert.That(CType(Prop1, Object), [Is].SameAs(Prop1))
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.